# wget recursive downloads only index file

Tags: wget

I followed one of the answers provided in [in this post](https://superuser.com/questions/104488/how-to-recursively-download-an-entire-web-directory) to download a blog's posts, and only that, no external links, but the recursive feature does not seem to work, as only the index file is downloaded. Any suggestions?

```
$ wget      --recursive   --page-requisites      --html-extension      --convert-links      --restrict-file-names=windows      --domains https://bestblog.wordpress.com/  https://bestblog.wordpress.com/
--2018-07-21 10:26:35--  https://bestblog.wordpress.com/
Resolving bestblog.wordpress.com (bestblog.wordpress.com)... 192.0.78.13, 192.0.78.12
Connecting to bestblog.wordpress.com (bestblog.wordpress.com)|192.0.78.13|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: unspecified [text/html]
Saving to: ‘bestblog.wordpress.com/index.html’

bestblog.wordpress.     [ <=>                ]  65.36K  --.-KB/s    in 0.09s   

2018-07-21 10:26:36 (729 KB/s) - ‘bestblog.wordpress.com/index.html’ saved [66929]

FINISHED --2018-07-21 10:26:36--
Total wall clock time: 0.4s
Downloaded: 1 files, 65K in 0.09s (729 KB/s)
Converting links in bestblog.wordpress.com/index.html... 6-25
Converted links in 1 files in 0.002 seconds.
```

Answer (score 0):

You should specify the `--domains` flag without the scheme:

```
--domains bestblog.wordpress.com
```